# How to get text in textbox inside an asp.net repeater on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I bind data to the repeater on Page Init:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            repeaterInfo.DataSource = //getDataSource;
            repeaterInfo.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Here's the markup page

```
<table class="beautifulTable">
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterInfo" OnItemCreated="repeaterInfo_ItemCreated">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td style="display: none">
               <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="90%" ID="txtUserInput"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Here's the Item created event:

```
protected void repeaterInfo_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.DataItem == null)
                return;
            
            TextBox txtUserInput= e.Item.FindControl("txtUserInput") as TextBox;
            txtUserInput.Text = "0.0"; //Default value
        }
```

And I would like to save the user input to database when the user clicks the submit button:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            List<repeaterType> source = repeaterInfo.DataSource as List<repeaterType>;
            for (int z = 0; z < source.Count; z++)
            {
                TextBox txtUserInput = repeaterInfo.Items[z].FindControl("txtUserInput") as TextBox;
                //Get text and do logic here
            }
            //Saves data to database
}
```

And here's the problem:

> The repeaterInfo datasource is null on postback
>
> If I remove the !IsPostBack, the txtUserInput text will be resetted (0.0)

I've enabled the viewstate on the markup page using `EnableViewState="true"`

How I can get the text in txtUserInput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repeater's datasource is not persisted in cross postbacks. If you just want to iterate and get the user inputs, you can just iterate through the items and get those like this:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeaterInfo.Items)
{
    if(item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        var txtUserInput = item.FindControl("txtUserInput") as TextBox;
    }
}
```

If you want the datasource to be persisted (may be to avoid database calls), use the `ViewState` (watch out for large number of rows):

```
ViewState["myDataSource"] = myDatasource;
```

Comment: I added more detail to my question: actually I am trying to get the user input in the repeater when the user clicks the submit button, so the problem is, if I save the datasource in ViewState and bind it again on postback, the user input will loss. So how should I overcome this problem?

Comment: The user inputs will not be lost, as you are capturing those by iterating `repeaterInfo.Items`

Comment: Then should I rebind the data on postback?

Comment: If you want to show updated data after submission, you need to rebind.